# Help me to create images and save them in folder through String passed in POST parameter

Tags: php

Hi Guys i am using following code to get the uploaded image

```
$imagedata= 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
               . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
               . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
               . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

$imagedata= base64_decode($imagedata);

    if(($img = @imagecreatefromstring($imagedata)) !== FALSE) 
    {
               //$filedb is having path string
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagedata']['tmp_name'], $filedb))
          { 
             echo 'success';
          }
          else
           {
                         echo 'error 1';
          }
    }
   else
   {
        echo 'error 2';
   }
```

I have checked that the image composed successfully but i am doing something wrong in passing  parameters to $_FILE[ ? ][ ? ] 
as a result i am getting result as error 1
Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
if(($img = @imagecreatefromstring($imagedata)) !== FALSE) 
{
      if( imagepng($img, $filedb) )
      { 
         echo 'success';
      }
      else
      {
        echo 'error 1';
      }

}
```

Comment: This code is wrong and will not run. imagepng takes the image resource handle then the path as arguments.

Comment: Yes, Dan u r right we have to pass first parameter of type resource and second destination.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between the image you created from a string, and something in `$_FILES`. `$_FILES` is only populated if files are uploaded as part of a form submitted to your script.

If you just want to save the image you created from the string, get rid of all the code after `imagecreatefromstring` and use `imagejpeg`, `imagegif` or `imagepng` to write the file.

Comment: ya man , i have checked that the image is created successfully, but i m failing to save the image to a particular directory, and as a result getting error 1 of inner else

Comment: ok it means $_FILES is of no use here , then please guide me what to use, I will b thankful 2 u  :)

Comment: I gave you the 3 functions you can use to write $im to a file depending on the format you want. Look them up at http://www.php.net if you need the syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot , really helpful functions

Comment: hey man , dont want to hurt u , Ur Answer was really really helpful for me , while mridkash simply write the code for the concept u have provided.

Comment: It was one line of code, and he didn't even do it right. His code will not run. You need `imagepng($img, $filedb)`.